# Videos are playing in greyscale when laptop is plugged in

Tags: windows-10, laptop, video, windows-10-v1803

Recently, in Windows 10, videos have been playing with the wrong colors when my laptop is plugged in.

If I play a video while plugged in, it looks like this:

[image: Image of greyscale video]

The only color in it is the yellow circle around the cursor (which is now a yellow green), and the yellow lines on the road (which are now darker).

However, if I unplug the charger and press Play again, the video looks like this:

[image: Image of normal video]

Without the charger plugged in, the video plays just fine.

I ran the Video playback troubleshooter, but got a "Troubleshooting couldn't identify the problem" message.

How can I fix this? I have a Dell Inspiron 3541 with Windows 10 v1803.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions :

1. If your computer is one of those that have Catalyst, go to the
   Catalyst Control center > Video > Color, and do Restore defaults.
2. If the issue occurred only recently, try a system restore to an earlier time
3. In Control Panel > Power options,
   click "Show additional plans" and tick "High Performance".
4. In Control Panel > Power options > Change plan settings > Change advanced power settings, expand "Graphics Processor" and "GPU Power State", and set
   the "Plugged in" value to "Max Performance".
5. In PC Settings > Ease of Access > Color filters,
   set to Off under "Turn on color filters".